# Where to put helper methods?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a method that darkens a given hex color and percent. Currently, the only place I use this method is within one of my `Activity` classes (I may or may not end up using it in other classes later on).

```
public static int darkenColor(int color, int percent) { ... }
```

However, where should I put this method? Should I create a new class called `Helpers` that contains all of these methods that I may use only once throughout the entire app?

Comment: For static methods that could be reused elsewhere, I tend to prefer grouping them into relevant `Utils` classes like `BitmapUtils`, `ImageUtils` etc, rather than having one class as a dumping ground for all of them. A `Helper` generally implies that the class would have some form of instance, so I'd avoid using that in the name.

Comment: Reusing snippets is a great idea. Primarily because you don't have to re-write code. public static methods, however, are usually not a good idea. The reason for that is because static methods break a fundamental rule of OOP languages called "encapsulation". Furthermore, static methods or member_variables are treated as "application level variables". Public and static combo does not only "scream" "bad design", but they are also much harder to clean, keep track of. Use private non static as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a matter of choice. You can have Set of utility classes and have these helper methods to be in those classes. But, This method is for not used in one of your activity, and If you do not see that it will get reused in the near future in some other point, Put it as a private method inside your Activity. I say this because you do not want to over complicate the code and also By this way another developer can easily follow the flow of execution.

But after sometimes if you feel, that this code is getting reused, put that into a logically meaningful Utility class. When the code base is huge, you do not have any choice to follow a solid standardization of there to put your code, That is why there are things like Layered architectures etc.